# I am receiving an error when saving PDF in Expo on iOS

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am developing using react-native and the expo client. I have code for saving html that is converted to a PDF. I then save it to the user's phone using the FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync() method. This works on Android but produces the following error on iOS: 'Unhandled promise rejection. This file type is not yet supported'.

```
let options = {
    html:html,
    base64:true,
  }
  const newPDF = await Print.printToFileAsync(options);
  const base64 = newPDF.uri;
  var path = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'App.pdf';

  if(this.state.downloadType=='qr-codes'){

    path = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'QRCodes.pdf';

  }else if(this.state.downloadType=='door-details'){

    path = FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'DoorDetails.pdf';

  }

  await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(path, base64);
  const asset = await MediaLibrary.createAssetAsync(path);
  await MediaLibrary.createAlbumAsync("Download", asset, false);

  alert("PDF Downloaded Successfully!");
```